# CSS is not styling my HTML

Tags: html, css

`<div class="entry">` is the root div.

Page CSS:

```
.entry h3 {
  font-family: Helvetica
  font-size: 30px
```

Now the problem is I have another div

```
<div class="widget">
  <h3 class="widget-title"</h3>
```

I want to change font size and font family of the above `h3` (`.widget-title`) but I cant as I have to delete the font size and family of `.entry h3`. I don't want to delete `.entry h3`

**UPDATE:**

I fixed the issue by adding `!important`. I hope this post helps someone else.

Comment: Can you use a full example of your code, not just fragment please.

Comment: what are you looking do. Do you need to override font-size and family of your h3

Comment: without full example of code how can we give you perfect answer for solve your issue :)

Comment: Yes Jithin, because if I edit .entry h3 then it will affect all other pages as well.

Comment: This is the full code Rajpal

Comment: you really don't need to use `!important` declarations to do this, and should avoid it, when possible.  You're better off using more accurate selectors and better structured CSS.

Comment: Then can you tell me how to fix this issue? Thanks

Comment: Sure, Check the snippet in my answer below.  Adding `!important` rules just makes your code more difficult to maintain over time.  It's not unheard of, just best to avoid it when possible.

Comment: The title of this question doesn't describe the issue!

Comment: In the code you supplied, the `h3` is not in an `.entry` so `.entry h3` will not target the `h3.widget-title`. And `<h3 class="widget-title"</h3>` is not valid html

Comment: Someone changed the title Gil !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to delete anything. That's not how stylesheets work.  Define your `.entry h3`, then just provide your widget title css after that.  Stylesheets cascade, remember.

**Also your H3 in your code example is missing a `>`.**

```css
.entry h3 {
  color: blue;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: serif;
  }

h3.widget-title {
  color: red;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  }
```

```html
<div class="entry">
  <h3>Entry Title H3</h3>
  <div class="widget">
    <h3 class="widget-title">
        Widget Title H3
    </h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Additionally, if you want to follow how your .entry h3 CSS class works and catch all h3 inside of widget class, you can swap h3.widget-title for .widget h3

Comment: Font size and family still doesn't change

Comment: Actually it does.. Re-run it.  I just added `font-family` and `font-size`.  If that's not working in your implementation then you have other rules in your css effecting this.  Check your inspector and see what CSS is effecting your h3 elements.

Comment: You were right!..There was another CSS affecting my h3 elements. I dont have to use !important now...Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It should not be an issue if you specifically target that element like below:

```
.entry h3 {
   font-family: Helvetica;
   font-size: 30px
}

.widget-title h3{
   font-family: serif !important;
   font-size: 30px
}
```

Comment: please show your code, there has to be a conflict somewhere

Answer (score 0):

Use `!important` in front of css styles

```
.widget-title{
 font-family: Helvetica !important
  font-size: 30px !important
}
```

Comment: Thanks Majid Azarniush

Comment: Please mark this as the answer to close the question if it has solved your problem rather than just saying "Thanks it worked"

Comment: I am new here..I didn't know that.

Comment: If you are using !important in your code, you are probable doing something wrong

Comment: Cabbage, there is a "check mark" near the answer , click on it, it will be colored green, that's how to make it as the answer, so the one who helped you can be rewarded.